# Sympy Matrix.col_insert not working python 3

Tags: python, sympy

So i have tried the following code copied straight from the docs, and it seems to me the function is not doing what it is supposed to:

```
import sympy as sp
M = sp.Matrix(3,3,lambda i,j: i+j)
V = sp.Matrix.zeros(3, 1)
M.col_insert(1,V) 
print(M)
```

gives the output

```
Matrix([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
```

not as per teh docs [link](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.col_insert).

```
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 2, 3]
[2, 0, 3, 4]
```

The same goes for row_insert.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so i tried it in the live shell on the website and there it is working. I am using the 0.7.6-git version with python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 3 (and earlier) I get the following

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> M = sp.Matrix(3,3,lambda i,j: i+j)
>>> V = sp.Matrix.zeros(3, 1)
>>> M.col_insert(1,V)
Matrix([
[0, 0, 1, 2],
[1, 0, 2, 3],
[2, 0, 3, 4]])
>>> print(M)
Matrix([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
```

`M` is not modified in place, a new matrix is created with the `col_insert` method -- notice that I didn't print anything after that command, the new matrix was returned by the command itself. The method `col_del`, on the other hand, works in place:

```
>>> M.col_del(0)
>>> M
Matrix([
[1, 2],
[2, 3],
[3, 4]])
```